# Need to display only the latest record from each ID and display the sum of each category using php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried everything to figure this out but I can't get the correct total. My attempts either add all the records and not just the latest ones or I only get the first record.

My first table: hubs

```
hubID    hubName
1           hub1
2           hub2
```

My second table: hub_reports

```
reportID    hubID          date          health         school 
1               1          2012-04-27    467            322 
2               2          2012-04-23    267            22 
3               1          2012-01-20    176            623
```

So what you see is 2 tables, one with the organizations name and other info and the second with the reports that each organization submits quarterly. I want to list all the organizations and their latest report. At the bottom of the table I want to add all the available health kits and school kits that are currently available.

Here's the code I'm using right now to display all the organizations and their latest reports.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT hubName, date, health, school FROM hub_reports,
hubs WHERE hub_reports.hubID = hubs.hubID ORDER BY date DESC) AS Total
GROUP BY hubName
```

This seems to work but when I try the same tactic to get the SUM of the health and school columns I don't get the right answer.

```
SELECT SUM(health) FROM (SELECT hubName, date, health FROM
hub_reports, hubs WHERE hub_reports.hubID = hubs.hubID ORDER BY date
DESC) AS Total GROUP BY hubName
```

I tried other using a LEFT JOIN approach that I found on another forum but it didn't seem to work any better. But I maybe I wasn't doing it right.

Please help!

Comment: But if you only want the latest health report, why do you need a SUM for the hub?

Comment: I want the latest report for each hub. I'm listing all the hubs, how many of the kits in each category they have on location and at the bottom adding all the kits in each category up so they can see what they have available throughout the whole organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just encountered a similar problem in a project of mine. A variation of this query worked for me. Hope it is helpful to you.

```
SELECT hubs.hubName, hub_reports.*, 
SUM(hub_reports.health) AS ttl_health, 
SUM(hub_reports.school) AS ttl_school
FROM hubs, hub_reports 
WHERE hub_reports.hubID = hubs.hubID 
GROUP BY hub_reports.hubID
ORDER BY hub_reports.date DESC
```

Here's the PHP:

```
$rs = mysql_query( 'SELECT hubs.hubName, hub_reports.*, 
    SUM(hub_reports.health) AS ttl_health, 
    SUM(hub_reports.school) AS ttl_school
    FROM hubs, hub_reports 
    WHERE hub_reports.hubID = hubs.hubID 
    GROUP BY hub_reports.hubID
    ORDER BY hub_reports.date DESC' );

$grand_total['school']=0;
$grand_total['health']=0;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs ) ){ // Step through each hub
    echo "{$row['hubName']} shows {$row['ttl_school']} total school, {$row['ttl_health']} total health";
    $grand_total['school'] += $row['ttl_school'];
    $grand_total['health'] += $row['ttl_health'];
}

echo "Grand Total School: {$grand_total['school']}, Grand Total Health: {$grand_total['health']}";
```

Comment: Can you show me how you would echo the value of ttl_health? I keep getting the first value of the array, not the sum.

Comment: I updated with some PHP code, let me know if you still have questions/troubles

Comment: You are helping me out so much! Thanks for your time. I see what your doing but this isn't quite what I'm looking for yet. I'm looking for the total of health kits from all three (there will be more later) hubs listed. Then all the school kits and so on. Here's the link to the page I'm working on. http://www.missioncentral.org/hubs/hubs_report_all.php

Comment: I see what you mean! You can easily tabulate the totals in the `while()` loop. See updates above and let me know if this is closer.

Comment: Ok, so we're so close I can taste it! I updated my page so you can see all the records. The grand totals are still adding all the records instead of just the newest ones. It took me a little but I see what it's doing. Instead of not counting the older records, it's adding them all together. The query is only showing 3 records, one for each hub, that's what we want. But if you look at the numbers for health kits you'll see Fawn had 11 and 34. The 34 shouldn't be counted since it's report date is older then the 11 but what it did was add 11 and 34 to get the 45 it's showing in the totals.

Comment: What if we change the two += lines to += $row['school'] and += $row['health'] (instead of $row['ttl_school'] and $row['ttl_health']) - I think that might get the totals you're looking for. If so, we can adjust the query since we don't need ttl_school and ttl_health sum() calculations any longer.

Comment: Got it!! I did what you said and it got rid of the adding the old and new record together to make 45 but I was still ending up with the 34 instead of 11. I took my original query I was using since that seemed to get the right numbers I just couldn't get them to add up, plugged that in place of what we had and bang. That was it! Thanks so much for your help. I've never had a problem haunt me like this one. I was always so close but just couldn't get it right.

Comment: Glad I could help! Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes looking at it from another angle. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for the `MAX()` function.

Try this:

```
SELECT h.hubID, h.hubname, MAX(hr.date) as hrdate, SUM(hr.health) as health, SUM(hr.school) as school
FROM hubs h
LEFT JOIN hub_reports hr ON hr.hubID = h.hubID
GROUP BY h.hubID
```

**Edit**

You want the MAX date so it only returns the most recent entry (assuming your entries are entered by date, of course).